# Cropping an image on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following data both in my js file or as a param in rails. Togther there is an image that is to be sent to server, what I want to achieve is to crop the image based on the data such as below. I am not allowed to use gems :) just using ruby/js code if I can manipulate the image already in js side. I am using cropper js which generated the output to me. What should I do to achieve cropping ?
    `{"x":552.697358490566,"y":-72.49509433962258,"width":696.9599999999999,"height":696.9599999999999,"rotate":0,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1}`

Comment: Could you show the javascript you're using to generate this output?

Comment: Using cropper.js ..    
$image.cropper({    
      aspectRatio: 1,
      autoCropArea: 1,
      strict: true,
      guides: true,
      highlight: true,
      background: true,
      dragCrop: false,
      cropBoxMovable: false,
      cropBoxResizable: true,
      preview: "#primary-file-upload-area", 
      mouseWheelZoom: true,
      viewMode: 3,
      minContainerHeight: 100,
      minContainerWidth: 100,
      doubleClickToggle: true,
      rotatable: false,

      },      
      crop: function(data) { x = data.x, width = data.width etc... } **

Comment: Could you show a bit more code? I'd like to know how is the data coming from your rails params to your Javascript. Are you trying to achieve the crop shown exactly on your input json?

Comment: Actually I am sending the data shown above as json param to rails controller, thinking then I can manipulate the image in controller with these attributes.

Comment: Hey, @KB_enreach, did my answer work for you?

Comment: Thanks for asking, looks like I donot understand what the end result of your suggestion is, for me it just puts the cropper box on the image creating three img elements.

Comment: Or in other words, how can I get to cut out the selection only and save the new image in my server. What is the way to proceed. Thanks a lot @peace

Comment: Okay, I have updated the answer to include what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the fiddle: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/30rcsox6/6/)

This is the code you should be using, since your JSON is already formatted the same way Cropper takes its input:

```
//get the data from your rails framework and save it in a variable, below I just pasted the same data you put in your question
var data = {"x":552.697358490566,"y":-72.49509433962258,"width":696.9599999999999,"height":696.9599999999999,"rotate":0,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1};

//remember to change my-picture to the id of your img
$('#my-picture').cropper('setData', data);

//also make sure to bind this to your own button
$('#crop-button').click(function(e){

    //this will transform the image into a blob, so you can submit it in form data
    $(this).href = $('#my-picture').cropper("getCroppedCanvas").toBlob(function (blob) {
      var formData = new FormData();

      formData.append('croppedImage', blob);

        //this is where you put your Rails path to upload
        //it's going to be a POST, so you should know how to handle it

      $.ajax('/path/to/upload', {
        method: "POST",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function () {
          console.log('Upload success');
        },
        error: function () {
          console.log('Upload error');
        }
      });
    });
});
```